# Sending Mandrill Email from C#

Tags: c#, mandrill

I have a Mandrill email template defined which I would like to send. Before sending I would like to replace certain parameters defined in the template.
For example, one of the emails is for Forgot Password and I would like to replace the new password in the template for parameter `|NEW_PASSWORD|`

My template was created in MailChimp and imported into Mandrill and I am using the following .Net Library:

### Here is the code I have so far

```
var api = new MandrillApi(api_key);

var recipients = new List<Mandrill.Messages.Recipient>();

recipients.Add(new Mandrill.Messages.Recipient(user_email, user_name));

Mandrill.NameContentList<string> content = new Mandrill.NameContentList<string>();

MVList<Mandrill.Messages.SendResult> result = api.SendTemplate(template, content, message);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Rohit

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You might want to consider an email templating service, instead of interfacing with Mandrill directly. Checkout sendwithus.com or customer.io. Both make it much easier to manage variables, and work well with C#.

Comment: Thank You for your advice. But Why add another interface between Mandrill and application? Mandrill templates expose variables, so just to get those to work, adding another interface in between does not seem sound to me.

Comment: I'm using the code on https://gist.github.com/andyhuey/3444063 and whilist I really do not know the context in which this is executed, I believe it's good enough to get a grasp in how merge variables should work.

Answer (score 3):

1)install nuget package from

https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet

2)in you template add placeholder like.
{{vendor_name}}

3)replace placeholder using global_merge_vars in api.

they provided 
AddGlobalVariable method with placeholder name and value which you want to replace.

```
            Mandrill.Models.EmailMessage email = new Mandrill.Models.EmailMessage();
            email.FromEmail = "teste@xxx.com";
            email.Subject = "Mandrill API Template Replace";
            email.RawMessage = "Hello Pradip Patel";
            email.MergeLanguage = "handlebars";

            email.AddGlobalVariable("vendor_name", "FI Test");
            //your template name
            string TemplateName = "Your Template Name.";

            email.To = new List<Mandrill.Models.EmailAddress>()
                {
                  new Mandrill.Models.EmailAddress("pradippatel1411@gmail.com")
                };

            Mandrill.Requests.Messages.SendMessageTemplateRequest objTemp = 
                new Mandrill.Requests.Messages.SendMessageTemplateRequest(email, TemplateName);

            var results = await api.SendMessageTemplate(objTemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use handlebars as Merge Language on mandrill http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html

Then I send variables which hold the same names as in the template, or even full objects which hold same members name to match what variables in the templates and then Handlebar and Mandrill handle mapping these to the template.